# Can I get a badge more than once?

Tags: support, badges

If I get a badge once, can I get another if I do the same thing again?

Say for example the ["Stellar Question" badge](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/36/stellar-question):

[image]

If I have 2 questions favorited by 100 or more users, do I get the badge twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Only if the badge says so.

You should check the respiective badge's page.

Example, a badge which *can* be earned multiple times (highlight by me):

> [image]

However, if a badge doesn't specifically say that it *can* be earned multiple times, **assume it can't**:

> [image]

Comment: You are true but can I find a way to list all badges that have this option (multiple times) without searching them 1 by 1

Comment: There's no official easy to read list, but you can check [this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) which describes each badge and whether they can be earned multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

**Depends on the badge.** Badges such as  Autobiographer(awarded when the user completes all user profile fields) are not awarded everytime the user completes all fields(if he removes/edits any field).

However, badges such as Stellar question (Question favorited by 100 users) awarded to the OP everytime a (new) question is favourited by 100 users.<sup>[[1]](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/36/stellar-question)</sup>